# Print before space from the string in Smarty

Tags: smarty

I have a date string in smarty template ( **{$date[s].d}** ) which includes date and time like this:

> > Dec-23-2012 09:00:00 AM

i want to remove everything after space so it would be like this

> > Dec-23-2012

i can do it in php but i need to do it in smarty template, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as an answer to my own question,
i managed to use |truncate, count 11 characters and remove the remaining

```
{$date[s].d|truncate:11:"":true}
```

this prints the following

```
    Dec-23-2012
```

if any one has a better idea i'll be happy to hear